# Why isn't the <div> with classname="comments" not rerendering even though the it's style property is changed on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am a newbie in react.js and js , please consider it while answering the question.
I'm trying to toggle the visibility of the comment box that I have created when a button is clicked. I am using 'usestate' hook to set the initial state and toggle the visibility state when button is clicked. Even though the state is getting updated when the button is clicked, comment box isn't rerendered with the updated state.

**APP.js**

```jsx
import React,{useState} from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "./main.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    item: state.item
  };
}

function App(props) {
  var [visibility,switchVisibility]=useState("visible"); 
  switchVisibility = () => {
    console.log(visibility,"outside")
    if(visibility==="hidden"){
      visibility="visible"
      console.log(visibility,"visible")
    }
    else{
      visibility="hidden"
      console.log(visibility,"hidden") 
    }

  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="Mainheader">
        <p className="header-cont">Pro1</p>
      </header>
        <div className="Mainitem">
          <div className="Itemwrapper">
            <div className="Tabledetails">
              <p className="Table">table</p>
              <p className="Tnumber">12</p>
              <p className="Orderedat">order given at</p>
              <p className="Time">1:10 PM</p> 
            </div>
            <div className="Button" onClick={switchVisibility}>
              <p style={{ marginTop: "0px", marginLeft: "4px" }}>CLOSE</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="divider" />

          <div className="Maindetails">
            {props.item.map((value,index)=>{console.log(value)
              return(
              <div key={index} className="plate-item">
              <div className="item-name">{value.itemName}</div>
              <div className="item-number">
                <p
                  style={{
                    border: "3px solid #5FD0E2",
                    marginTop: "0px",
                    height: "19.74px",
                    width: "32.63px",
                    marginBottom: "8px"
                  }}
                >
                {value.itemNumber}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            )})}

            <div className="comments" style={{ visibility: visibility }}>
              <p className="commentText">No comment</p>
            </div>


          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**INDEX.js**

```jsx
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log("reducer", state, action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "CLOSE":
      if (state.visibility === "visible") {
        return {
          visibility: "hidden"
        };
      } else {
        return {
          visibility: "visible"
        };
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
const initialState = {
  item: [{ 
  itemName : "Fried Rice",
  itemNumber: 2,
  comments: "No Comments",
  visibility: "Visible"
  },
  { 
    itemName : "Chicken 65",
    itemNumber: 4,
    comments: "No Comments",
    visibility: "Invisible"
    },
    { 
      itemName : "Mackan 65",
      itemNumber: 6,
      comments: "No Comments",
      visibility: "Invisible"
      }]
};
const store = createStore(reducer);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.register();
```

Comment: I see some chaos in the code above. You are using React state (`useState`) but seems you are also using redux for managing the same state.
Try to keep things simple (remove redux for now)

Answer (score 0):

Your `switchVisibility` function must receive the new state as first argument and **you must not (never!)** modify the state variable (`visibility`) by yourself.
You are also reassigning `switchVisibility` to a new function.

I suggest you to read carefully [the setState hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), seems you are missing some basical knowledge of hooks.

So: it should be something like this:

```
<div className="Button" onClick={() => {
  if(visibility==="hidden"){
    switchVisibility("visible")
  }
  else{
    switchVisibility("hidden")
  }
}}>
  <p style={{ marginTop: "0px", marginLeft: "4px" }}>CLOSE</p>
</div>
```